# find $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n= \left(\frac{e\sqrt[3]{e}...\sqrt[n]{e}}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to determine the limit of the sequence  $$x_n=\left(\frac{e\sqrt[3]{e}...\sqrt[n]{e}}{n}\right)$$

Since the sequence is of the form $x_n=\frac{v_n}{v_n}$ with $v_n$ a positively divergent sequence, I thought to apply the Stolz criterion and find the limit of $$x_n=\frac{{v_{n+1}}-u_n}{v_{n+1}-v_n}$$

However I don't get anything concrete that allows me to find the limit, any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$  x_n=\frac{e}{n}\prod_{k=3}^n e^{\frac{1}{k}}=\frac{e}{n}e^{H_n-\frac{3}{2}}=e^{1-\log n+(\log n+\gamma+o(1))-\frac{3}{2}}=e^{\gamma-\frac{1}{2}+o(1)} $$
Therefore the desired limit is $e^{\gamma-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help